# Android browser which is always in Readable view

Tags: android, web-browser

I'd like to browse the internet from a Readability mode similar to what [Readability](https://www.readability.com/about)/[Instapaper](https://www.instapaper.com/apps) achieve without creating 'reading lists' from the browser, but instead going to any site will automatically the styling is applied.

So in short: a browser that shows a simple readable format of websites like Readability, from where you  can continue browsing and enter links/searches.

[image: Readabiliy App on Android]